# MacBookPro10,1 had problems booting, now some system images are pink and fuzzy

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, graphics

A friend just recently bought a MacBookPro10,1 (MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012) off of craigslist, it all checked out and worked fine until we erased the hard drive and reinstalled Mavericks (downloaded Mavericks from AppStore on my computer and used [DiskMaker X v3.0.4](http://diskmakerx.com/) to create a bootable usb).

It would go through first stage of install (copying files), but after reboot it would hang on the Apple logo plus spinning gear thing. We figured out it would only boot in Safe Mode.

After a few hours of reinstalling and resetting stuff like NVRAM/PRAM and trying to get into AHT(unsuccessfully) and a bunch of other things, it finally would boot normally(without Safe Mode or any other keys pressed on boot).

It was very exciting, except on further use, some of the system images would come up odd colors and distorted/noisy. And it even freezes sometimes.

[image: Example of graphical corruption]

I guess it might be a graphics issue(?), but what would cause only some images to be like this? Is it still recoverable? Has anyone else had similar issues?

I really appreciate any help in advance! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your USB did not contain the clean bootable version.

I would suggest you start over and follow the [procedure from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856).

You can get a copy of 10.9.5 from here or from Apple Store.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1761

Make sure the USB is single partition and minimal 8 Gig. (no other partitions on that disk)

Comment: Thanks, when we did that, the install did go better! And we were finally able to get into the Apple Hardware Tests. But, it gave us a code we [figured out](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/finding-hardware-faults-exploring-aht-apple-diagnostics--mac-60456) was related to an electrical sensor for DC. We did a SMC reset, and then did an AHT extended test. And then it gave a code related to power bus temperature.
The person my friend bought it from was nice enough to let my friend return it if there were any hardware issues, so I think they are just going to return it.

Comment: Which I realize is a completely different problem (probably) from what I originally described, but none the less still an issue. I guess your answer was the solution to the original problem, so I'll accept it, even though there are still existing problems.

Like also when we plugged in the USB, it crashed the computer (full gray screen with black text, nothing can be done except force shutdown). But if the USB is in before it boot, no crash.

Anyway, thanks for the help. I didn't know Apple made a utility to create bootable USBs. I'll be using that instead of DiskMaker X from now on!

Comment: Well, we got it to install and boot :) the other problems are other problems, but since now you can access it use the Console log and report (in a new post) the problems., or just return it. From your initial report they do not look like major and maybe fixable.

Comment: I posted the other question about the USB thing here [http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147860/55251](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147860/55251)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post and the other one at [MacBookPro10,1 goes to gray screen when a USB is inserted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147860/macbookpro10-1-goes-to-gray-screen-when-a-usb-is-inserted) :

I would say that you're probably looking at a faulty logic board. The system should be taken into a Genius Bar or an authorized Apple repair centre for further evaluation and/or repair.